# PostGIS strange difference in distance calc from different point defenitions

Tags: coordinates, postgis-2.0

I have a working POSTGIS database, loaded Dutch CBS data using shp2pgsql and now I want to map lat,lon coordinates to multipolygons.

All examples I see use lon lat coordinates but if I do so I get huge distance to my geom objects... If I use coordinates from http://epsg.io/28992/map# it works...

```
SELECT gm_naam, 
st_distance(geom, ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(5.112472, 52.008417),28992) ) as dist,
ST_Distance(geom, ST_SetSRID(ST_Point(134989.82, 448191.66),28992) ) as dist2
FROM nlstaging.gem_2013
order by dist2 Asc
```

The result is like this:

```
gm_naam dist    dist2
Nieuwegein  465085.92145570647  0.0
IJsselstein 464133.17518803617  2018.4612972214297
Houten  463571.9453450817   2037.1431117615386
Vianen  459472.14358348626  2102.6589540861714
Utrecht 467845.0647365362   2308.3854923630483
```

So Nieuwegein is the right answer, dist2 is coorect calculation but the coordinates are NOT lon,lat ...

Question:
How can I specify a point using lon lat and have correct distance?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your table seems to be an Amersfoort oblique stereographic (EPSG:28992). To use a lon/lat point as input, you need to create it as a lon/lat point, then transform it, so your distance function would look something like this:

```
ST_Distance(geom, ST_Transform(ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(5.112472, 52.008417),4326),28992))
```